# Maven SVN checkout

Tags: svn, maven

Can anybody tell me how to make checkout and further updates from SVN with Maven? I read the documentation on maven.apache.org but it seems that i'm too dumb for this because i can't understand how to use scm:checkout and scm:update without passing them parameters in command line. I mean when i run just:

```
mvn scm:checkout (or scm:update) clean install
```

maven checks out sources to /target/checkout, then it deletes it and of course it has nothing to compile so it makes empty jar. So i have to write something like this:

```
mvn scm:checkout -DconnectionUrl=scm:svn:http://svn.my.dev/scm/repo/trunk/myProject -DcheckoutDirectory=src clean install
```

But i don't want to! How can i set these parameters inside pom.xml? And how can i set current directory as checkoutDirectory? (probably it should not be a problem if set it in pom.xml because i can set it as ${project.basedir}, but who knows) 
My pom.xml includes these lines:

```
...
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://svn.my.dev/scm/repo/trunk/myProject</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://svn.my.dev/scm/repo/trunk/myProject</developerConnection>
  </scm>
...
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <configuration>
      <username>username</username>
          <password>password</password>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
...
```

Btw, what is the difference between connection and developerConnection. Maven documentation says only that developerConnection is... "The SCM connection URL for developers". Which is very surprising for me 'cause i thought that this is some connection for squirrels or may be bunnies.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the `checkoutDirectory` option directly to the configuration of the maven-scm-plugin. Once the files are checked out, you can use `scm:update` with the `workingDirectory` option (can be configured in the plugin configuration as well)

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7</version>
  <configuration>
    <username>username</username>
    <password>password</password>
    <checkoutDirectory>${project.basedir}/src</checkoutDirectory>
    <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src</workingDirectory>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that works. But i still can't manage to set current directory as checkoutDirectory. If i set <checkoutDirectory>${project.basedir}</checkoutDirectory> (and same for workingDirectory) maven for some reason just cleans whole directory including pom.xml and exits saying that it can't remove the directory itself. It's not a big deal of course, i can use the mentioned "src" subdirectory as checkout and working directory but for me it would be better to use current directory for such usage. Is it possible?

Comment: No, I think this is not possible as Maven always deletes the checkout directory before making the checkout.
I don't know how your build setup exactly works but maybe you could commit your POM file together with your src/ directory (as most people do). If this is possible in your environment, you can run `mvn scm:checkout -DconnectionUrl=scm:svn:http://my-svn-url -DcheckoutDirectory="/my/checkout/directory"`. You can also put all the -D options in a "bootstrap" POM and just run `mvn scm:checkout` or `mvn scm:update`

Comment: Well, i made shell script which checkouts/updates projects and then runs maven build. Maven svn plugin, after all, needs svn installed anyway and svn shell commands are very easy so i don't see much sense in using maven svn plugin.